# Integral of Dirac Delta Derivative Times Non-Smooth Function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta, mathematica, non-smooth-analysis

I know that if we have some function f(y) that is smooth and has compact support, we get the following by using integration by parts.

$\int f(y) \delta '(y-x) dy = -\int f'(y) \delta (y-x) dy =-f'(x)$

And more generally we have the following statement.

$\int f(y) \delta ^{(n)}(y-x) dy = (-1)^n f^{(n)}(x)$

My problem is currently what do I do if $f(y)$ is not smooth. I am dealing with a case where $f'(y)$ isn't defined at the point $x$. For example, if I have $f(y) = 1/y$ and I'm considering the following integral is there anything that I can say about the value of this integral?

$\int \frac{1}{y} \delta ^{(n)}(y) dy$

In this case $f'(y) = -\frac{1}{y^2}$ which is undefined at $y=0$.

I've tried plugging the above integral into Mathematica for $n=1,2,3,4$ and I have gotten $0$ every time. I'm just not sure why that answer would make sense. Here is an example of the code I used

`Integrate[Derivative[4][DiracDelta][s]*(1/s), {s, 0, Infinity}]`

Comment: Maybe use [this limit representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/0014/) or [combine](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/0013/) [these](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Bcsch%28a+x%29%2C%7Bx%2Cr%7D%5D) identities and integrate?

Comment: What is your definition of the dirac delta function? Can you share your intuition why you think that $\int \frac{1}{y} \delta^{(n)}(y) dy$ is well-defined?

Comment: First of all, the limits of integration shouldn't start at zero. second, even if set from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ the answer given is $0$. I think the reason it does this is because it considers your function to be an odd function. If you try $1/|s|$ it doesn't converge.

Comment: You can't do this; distributions like Dirac delta must be integrated towards smooth functions ("test functions"). In fact, $1/y$ is itself a distribution and products of distributions are ill-defined, as you observed.

Comment: @Abezhiko Thank you I had the same thought. I'm mainly confused because Mathematica still evaluated the expressions. It didn't produce any errors it just popped out $0$. Do you have any idea how it went about evaluating the integral?

Comment: @DavidRaveh Thank you! That's helpful. Why can't I start it at 0? I know that it's an improper integral but can't I just use a limit to take care of that?

Comment: Thanks @TymaGaidash those are some interesting links. I'm going to think about it more in terms of that.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I'm just using the usual definition of dirac delta function. My only reason for thinking it is well-defined is that Mathematica evaluated it and got $0$. I'm not too sure why this should work out or how to go about evaluating it without computer aid (since the function $1/y$ is not smooth).

Comment: @DavidRaveh I actually just tried this input in Mathematica 'Integrate[Derivative[4][DiracDelta][s]*Abs[1/s], {s, 0, Infinity}]' and I also got $0$

Comment: Well, I do not know what mathematica does, but as was pointed out above, such an expression is ill-defined.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven okay thank you

Comment: @k12345 this is just my speculation. But note that Dirac delta function is an "even function", and derivative of even function is odd...so it might see fourth derivative as odd. Once again, you should always integrate over zero, since it is not well defined if start integral at zero